# Como hacer un llamado a una actividad de una app desde el navegador

Tags: html, android, chrome

este es mi primera pregunta e este portal, y estoy tratando de escribir el código de una tool-web, orientada para hacer accesos directos a algunas app ya instaladas y automatizar o simplificar algunas acciones, algo parecido a lo mencionado en

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250152/what-is-the-intent-to-launch-any-website-link-in-google-chrome/66481694#66481694

pero mi interés es en hacer un llamado a una actividad especifica dentro de una app, digamos poder llamar la función de smartlook de los servicios de google

yo uso por ejemplo esta funcion"**Google Seach**"

que me permite abrir el google serch desde el navegador, pero como puedo hacer que del paquete de PlayServices "com.google.android.gsm" al clickar un enlace en la pagina pueda acceder directamente a la actividad o función siguiente="com.google.android.gms.trustagent.discovery.WebpageOnbodyPromotionActivity"

desde aplicaciones como "Quickshortcutmaker" se puede realizar este llamado, pero quisiera evitar muchas vueltas y hacer un llamado directo desde mi web-tool. les agradezco mucho la ayuda que puedan aportar

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es usar [Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Puedes definir dentro del `intent-filter` que abre tu Activity principal, el dominio que deseas escribir en el navegador y este sugiera abrir tu app.

Por ejemplo si defines este esquema:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"          
        android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.stackoverflow.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

con el ejemplo anterior, al escribir en el navegador https://stackoverflow.com/ se sugerìra abrir tu app.

---

> al clickar un enlace en la pagina pueda acceder directamente a la
> actividad o función

Usando Deep Links el sistema operativo te sugerira abrir en el navegador o la aplicaciòn la url, pero no puede ser directamente.

Si desearas abrir una funciòn podrìas definir un `android:pathPattern`

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.stackoverflow.com" android:pathPattern="/WebpageOnbodyPromotionActivity/"/>
```

al abrir dentro de la aplicaciòn podrìas detectar este pathPattern y en base a esto abrir tu funciòn o decidir alguna funcionalidad dentro de la app, esto se realiza [leyendo los datos del Intent que se recibe al abrir la aplicaciòn](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#handling-intents).

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main)

        val action: String? = intent?.action
        val data: Uri? = intent?.data
    }
```

---

Te sugiero revisar la documentaciòn oficial:

[**Cómo agregar filtros de intents para vínculos entrantes**](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters)

Answer (score 0):

este es la clase codigo que estoy usando por ejemplo para llamar abrir apps:

```
<a href="intent://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/#Intent;scheme=android-app;end" data-wpel-link="internal"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><img height="20" src="search.png"/><strong>Google Seach</strong></a>
    <p>Envía directamente a google search de google now.</p>
```

estoy tratando de adaptar la info que compartes, pero aun no logro hacerlo funcionar.

```
<a href="intent://com.google.android.gsm/#Intent;scheme=android-app;android:pathPattern=com.google.android.gms.trustagent.discovery.WebpageOnbodyPromotionActivity;end" data-wpel-link="internal">
```

PD.: el codigo que estoy utilizando es bastante sencillo y no se mucho sobre programación html